# Displaying Error Message When Insert Fails

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna make it that if $floor and $spot is in the table already a error message will come up stating "spot taken". As of now it successfully sends out a email, but i would like it to display a error message if those variables are present in the table so I can avoid duplicate reservations, before sending out the email.

```
    // Insert data into mysql
        $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Confirmation, Fname, Lname, Gname, License, Floor, Spot )
        VALUES('$confirm_code', '$fname', '$lname', '$gname', '$license', '$floor',
'$spot')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // if suceesfully inserted data into database, send confirmation link to email 

          if($result){
     // ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if($result === FALSE)
{
    die("MySql-Query failed.");
} else {
   //send mail
}
```

Comment: What will cause it to fail? Also were would I put the error message - @tobias

Comment: An error in your sql query.
If this is not what you want to achieve you have to check first with a select if the values already exist in database.

Answer (score -1):

You can also check the mysql_error() value.

```
if(mysql_error() != ""){
    //There is an error
    Die(mysql_error());
}
```